# Pandas merge_asof with extra join key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a use case where `pd.merge_asof` seem to be the perfect solution. However there is an extension to this case where I would need to join on a key as well as use `pd.merge_asof`:

Consider dataframe A:

```
Index:   Key1:   Time:
A       x       9:30
B       y       12:30
C       y       14:30
D       z       9:30
```

And dataframe B:

```
Values:   Key1:   Time:
Albert       x       9:00
Bertha       x       10:00
Corry        y       12:00
Derk         y       13:00
Edd          z       9:00
Freek        z       10:00
```

Then, the desired result would look like

```
Index:   Key1:   Time:   Values:
A       x       9:30     Albert
B       y       12:30    Corry
C       y       14:30    Derk
D       z       9:30     Edd
```

So for example A and D have the same `Time` but get a different value since `Key1` is also used. Is there a method to use within `pd.merge_asof()` to achieve this or would we need to do some kind of loop?

Comment: What is the dtype of "Time"? Can you provide the constructors?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use:

```
pd.merge_asof(dfA.assign(t=pd.to_timedelta(dfA['Time']+':00'))
                 .sort_values(by='t'),
              dfB.assign(t=pd.to_timedelta(dfB['Time']+':00'))
                 .sort_values(by='t').drop(columns='Time'),
              on='t', by='Key1').drop(columns='t')
```

output:

```
  Index Key1   Time  Values
0     A    x   9:30  Albert
1     D    z   9:30     Edd
2     B    y  12:30   Corry
3     C    y  14:30    Derk
```

If order is important, temporarily `reset_index`:

```
(pd.merge_asof(dfA.assign(t=pd.to_timedelta(dfA['Time']+':00'))
                  .sort_values(by='t').reset_index(),
               dfB.assign(t=pd.to_timedelta(dfB['Time']+':00'))
                  .sort_values(by='t').drop(columns='Time'),
               on='t', by='Key1')
   .drop(columns='t')
.set_index('index').sort_index()
)
```

output:

```
      Index Key1   Time  Values
index                          
0         A    x   9:30  Albert
1         B    y  12:30   Corry
2         C    y  14:30    Derk
3         D    z   9:30     Edd
```

reproducible inputs:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'Index': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                    'Key1': ['x', 'y', 'y', 'z'],
                    'Time': ['9:30', '12:30', '14:30', '9:30']})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'Values': ['Albert', 'Bertha', 'Corry', 'Derk', 'Edd', 'Freek'],
                    'Key1': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z'],
                    'Time': ['9:00', '10:00', '12:00', '13:00', '9:00', '10:00']})
```